# Center items with aspect ratio in FlatList - React Native

Tags: css, react-native

This seems like an easy question at first but it's actually tricky.

Better to go directly to the example. I've created a snack with the sample code here https://snack.expo.io/BkSNtNrWV

I want to have a list of items with given aspect ratio (say 3:2) and the items should take as much space as possible with a maximum limit on size. This sample code does it:

```
<View>
    <FlatList style={{backgroundColor:'lightgray'}}
      data={[{key: 'a'},{key: 'b'}]}
      renderItem={({item}) => 
         <View style ={styles.pink}></View>
      }/>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    pink: {
         backgroundColor: "#A37E93",
         maxHeight: 150,
         aspectRatio: 3/2,
         borderWidth: 1,
  }});
```

And this is the result:
[image: items aligned to the left]

However, the problem is that I would like to have the items aligned to the center. I tried to wrap the list item in a flexbox with 'row' direction but that caused the item to have 0 height => not displayed. Justify content didn't help either (it's possible that I do it incorrectly).

Does anyone know how to solve this please?

Answer (score 0):

Updated the code. Add flex to inner item and wrap the view inside another with screen width.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,FlatList,Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

const{width} = Dimensions.get('window')

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList style={{backgroundColor:'lightgray'}}
          data={[{key: 'a'},{key: 'b'}]}
          renderItem={({item}) => 
            <View style={styles.item}>
            <View style ={styles.pink}></View>
            </View>
          }
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  item:{
   width:width,
   height:150,
   alignItems:'center'
  },
  pink: {
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor: "#A37E93",
        maxHeight:150,
        aspectRatio:3/2,
        borderWidth:1,
    }
});
```